# Why is C is much slower as compared to Java?

Tags: java, c, performance, gcc

So, I am completely new to C. I am testing the performance of the languages.

**What I did?**

I wrote 2 programs one in C one in java both doing the same thing but C is very slow as compared to Java?

Here are the programs:

**main.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h> 
#include <conio.h>

void work();

int main() {
    time_t seconds;     
    seconds = time(NULL); 
    printf("time1 : %ld\n", seconds);
    work();
    seconds = time(NULL); 
    printf("time2 : %ld\n", seconds);
    return 0;
}

void work() {
    int a[1000][500];
    for (int k = 0; k < 10000; ++k) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 500; ++j) { 
                a[i][j] = (i + j) * 5416585;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Main.java

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("time1 : " + (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000));
        work();
        System.out.println("time2 : " + (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000));
    }

    public static void work() {
        int a[][] = new int[1000][500];
        for (int k = 0; k < 10000; ++k) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 500; ++j) { 
                    a[i][j] = (i + j) * 5416585;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**My Question :-**

So, my question is by all what I have read C should be much faster as it is low level whereas Java itself runs on a Virtual Machine thus should be comparatively slower! But in my case the outputs were : -

```
C:\>gcc main.c

C:\>javac Main.java

C:\>a
time1 : 1610049457
time2 : 1610049468

C:\>java Main
time1 : 1610049474
time2 : 1610049478

C:\>a
time1 : 1610049487
time2 : 1610049498

C:\>java Main
time1 : 1610049501
time2 : 1610049505
```

Clearly Java is much faster than C here!

Why is this happening?

Comment: Why do you assume a VM should be slower?  (To say nothing of how this is a problematic way to measure performance of Java code.)

Comment: You C program most likely has an integer overflow, and invokes undefined behavior

Comment: no there are no errors shown

Comment: You are not using `k` for loop, maybe the Java compiler just takes it out and optimizes the program?

Comment: You are compiling in debug mode! Add -02 as a flag when compiling

Comment: I think the JIT optimizes your code, since your for loop size is constant and the flow of the program is mostly unaffected by external factors

Comment: When compiled with -O3, `work` is becoming nothing: https://godbolt.org/z/f5j711 And benchmarking something else is pointless

Comment: Which full optimizations, the C compiler's optimizer is outsmarting your test. It is able to determine the result at compile-time, so it simply prints the pre-calclated result at run-time, instead of calculating it at run-time.

Comment: change the pre-defined array to a dynamic array; change 5416585 to a random number; optimize the compilation of C; do the test again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default, GCC does not apply any optimizations, so the generated code is quite slow. In contrast, Java VMs enable most optimizations by default.

```
$ gcc main.c
$ time ./a.out 
time1 : 1610050160
time2 : 1610050167

real    0m7.113s
user    0m7.112s
sys 0m0.000s
$ gcc -O2 main.c
$ time ./a.out 
time1 : 1610050172
time2 : 1610050172

real    0m0.002s
user    0m0.002s
sys 0m0.000s
```

If you look at the generated assembler code, the body of the `work` function is optimized away in the optimized version:

```
work:
.LFB12:
    .cfi_startproc
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

Comment: For comparison, Java without optimization (`java -Xint Main`) runs in 56 seconds on my machine